# spring boot jms - send and receive message inside @JmsListner

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq

QUEUE_INI use IBM MQ9, latest spring boot, and IBM's spring-boot-starter.

I'd like to receive a message with @JmsListner, then without committing it, send another message to another queue, receive response and then commit all.

So far I has next:

```java
    @JmsListener(destination = QUEUE_IN, selector = "type='com.example.MainRequest")
    public void receiveMessage(Message message) throws JMSException {
        LOG.info("Received {} <{}>", QUEUE_IN, message);
        jmsTemplate2.convertAndSend(QUEUE_OUT, "SUB Request", requestMsg -> {
            requestMsg.setStringProperty("type", "com.example.SubRequest");
            return requestMsg;
        });
        LOG.info("Message sent");
        Message reply = jmsTemplate2.receiveSelected(QUEUE_IN, "type='com.example.SubResponse'");
        LOG.info("Received reply from {}: <{}>", QUEUE_IN, reply);
    }
```

I'm stuck on 'Message sent'. It looks like sub-request hasn't really sent. I see in MQ UI that queue depth is 1 but there is no message inside, and my sub-request listener also doesn't see any messages.

I've also tried use `sendAndReceive` method:

```java
Message reply = jmsTemplate.sendAndReceive(QUEUE_OUT, session -> {
    Message msg = session.createTextMessage();
    msg.setStringProperty("type", "com.example.SubRequest");
    LOG.info("Sending msg: <{}> to {}", msg, QUEUE_OUT);
    return msg;
});
```

But I do not have permissions to access model queue.

Is there any way to make this work?

UPDATE:
I made this work with combined help from you all. I end up with separate service to only send sub request with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`. All other logic remained within main listener.

Also turning on transactions start/end logs was helpful:

```yaml
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor: trace
```

Comment: Could you provide some clarifications in your question. `Model queue` implies dynamic queues, is this correct are you using a dynamic queue for the output message. In your code you appear to be listening for a message in `receiveSelected` for `QUEUE_IN`, should that not be `QUEUE_OUT` ?  I think you should receive the same insufficient permissions on the model queue for both sets of code.

Comment: @chughts I have permissions for regular queue. I send sub-request to ```QUEUE_OUT```. Another service will receive it and send reply back to ```QUEUE_IN```. So it is correct (there was a mistake in logging)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your outbound  message sender is enrolled in the same transaction as your message receiver. So the receiver of the outbound message won't see the message until the transaction commits. I think you need to start a new transaction to perform the inner procedure.

**== Update ==**

So it's been a while, and I don't have a dev environment set up for this, but I suggest something like this. Essentially, you're splitting up the Listener and Sender/Receiver into two separate classes. The Sender/Receiver should be injected into your listener so the @Transactional annotation is honored.

```
public class MyListener {
    private final MySender sender;

    public MyListener(MySender sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = QUEUE_IN, selector = "type='com.example.MainRequest")
    public void receiveMessage(Message message) throws JMSException {
        LOG.info("Received {} <{}>", QUEUE_IN, message);
        Message reply = sender.sendAndReceive()
        LOG.info("Received reply from {}: <{}>", QUEUE_IN, reply);
    }
}


public class MySender {
    private final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate2;
    private final Destination QUEUE_OUT;

    public MySender(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate2, Destination QUEUE_OUT) {
        this.jmsTemplate2 = jmsTemplate2;
        this.QUEUE_OUT = QUEUE_OUT;
    }

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NESTED)  // Or REQUIRES_NEW, edepending on usage
    public Message sendAndReceive() throws JMSException {
        jmsTemplate2.convertAndSend(QUEUE_OUT, "SUB Request", requestMsg -> {
            requestMsg.setStringProperty("type", "com.example.SubRequest");
            return requestMsg;
        });
        LOG.info("Message sent");
        Message reply = jmsTemplate2.receiveSelected(QUEUE_IN, "type='com.example.SubResponse'");
        LOG.info("Received reply from {}: <{}>", QUEUE_IN, reply);
        return reply;
    }
}
```

The @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NESTED) will start a new transaction if one is already running (and commit/rollback when the method exits), so you should be able to send/receive the message and return it to you listener.

Comment: Yeah, I also thought that. But adding TransactionManager bean and ```@Transactional``` annotation didn't help much. Could you please expand your answer? How can I achieve that?

Comment: As @Nicholas states you need to commit the `convertAndSend` in order for your 2nd application to see the message and reply to it. Without the commit the message is not visible to another application.

Comment: Nicholas, you are almost right. I had to split this to 2 separate classes. Somehow adding neither REQUIRED_NEW nor NESTED didn't work for me inside same class. No new transactions were started. But with 2 classes it's working. But, as @richc mentioned I had also split send and receive in order to commit sending

Comment: Alexander; Yeah, the thing with Annotations.... if the method is not injected into your current bean, it's not been pre-processed, so local method calls (one method to another in the same class/object instance) don't honor the annotations. I suppose there might be a way to do this, but it has escaped me.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I am unable to add a comment to the previous answer as I don’t have sufficient privilege.

As [@Nicholas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43786/nicholas) says, your message receive is in the same transaction as the message send. Until the `receiveMessage` method completes the initial send won’t be committed to the queue for the receiver to consume. I am assuming you might have the receive configured with something like `RECEIVE_TIMEOUT_INDEFINITE_WAIT` which would then block completion of the method.

With this configuration, you already have a Message Listener bound to `QUEUE_IN`. Messages delivered to that queue would be delivered to just one consumer. I see you are using selectors to avoid this problem.

One option might be to introduce another Message Listener for type = `com.example.SubResponse` and remove the blocking receive from the first.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. I had to split sending and receiving into separate methods. But I also had to begin separate transaction for sending.