# Use JmsTemplate to send JMS message from @JmsListener

Tags: java, jms, spring-jms

I am trying to send a JMS message from inside of a JmsListener. My code looks something like this:

```java
@Autowired
private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

@JmsListener(destination = "myQueue1")
public void receiveMessage(@Payload ObjectMessage message) {
     someWork1(); //takes few millisconds

     jmsTemplate.send(myQueue2);

     someWork2(); //takes a minute
}
```

In above scenario the consumer for `myQueue2` is not able to receive the message when execution time of the method is 1 min, and if `someWork2()` takes 10-15 seconds then `myQueue2` is able to receive the message successfully.

TTL settings

```
spring.jms.template.time-to-live=36000
```

Comment: Sounds like you are using transactions. The message is probably only sent out upon completion of the JmsListener annotated method? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68892932/16034206

Comment: @experimentunit1998X Yes the message is sent out only when the annotated method is completed, and I am not using any transaction on annotated method, i even tried using @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER) on the annotated method but no success

Comment: Maybe you could refer to this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63126115/16034206

Comment: Thanks for responding, I now tried @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NESTED) on the method which send message, still no luck.
But if I create a new thread and then send message from there then it works.

new Thread((){sendJmsMessage()}).start(); //works!